# What is wrong with an add method I declared in a class that sums two numbers?

Tags: python, class, methods

I have created the following class

```
class Adder:
  '''A class that adds its parameter'''
  def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.x = a
    self.y = b

    def add(self):
      return self.x + self.y
```

Then, I tried to use the add method to sum two numbers, as follows

```
adder = Adder(3, 4)
adder.add()
```

But I get the following error message:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 adder.add()

AttributeError: 'Adder' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Is the indentation error only in the pasted code or is it in the original code itself?

Comment: Your indentation is off. The function definition needs to be at the same level as `__init__`, currently, it is nested *inside* `__init__` so a function gets defined then immediately discarded

Answer (score 4):

You have an indentation error. When you are initializing your variables, you also have a function.
Keep that outside the initialize function but in your class.

```
class Adder:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.x = a
        self.y = b
    def add(self):
        return self.x + self.y
adder = Adder(3, 4)
adder.add()
```

Comment: Fantastico!!! This error was driving me crazy. Really appreciate your help.